# Pasar datos extra a través de res.view()

Tags: javascript, web, sailsjs

Estoy en un proyecto en `sailsjs`, en el cual debo enviar una vista desde el `backend` vía `ajax` y pintarla luego en pantalla.
Mi duda es: ¿Puedo enviar información además de la vista?
Un ejemplo:

```
res.view('contro/vista', {   // Estos datos son para la vista
    vista: vista,
    layout: 'ajax'
    }, {
    realizado: 1   // Estos datos son para acceder en el frontend.
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Según [la documentación](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/response-res/res-view#?example), los parámetros que le pasas a la plantilla van en el segundo argumento. Esto significa que si pones:

```
res.view('contro/vista', {   // Estos datos son para la vista
    vista: vista,
    layout: 'ajax',
    realizado: 1   // Estos datos son para acceder en el frontend.
  }
);
```

En tu front podrías usar:

```
<div>Valor de realizado es <%= realizado %></div>
```

O bien

```
<div>Valor de realizado es {{realizado}}</div>
```

Dependiendo de tu motor de plantillas y su manera de interpolar variables.

El motor es lo suficientemente inteligente para leer algunos parámetros clave (por ejemplo, el parámetro `layout` afecta al rendereo en sí) junto con parámetros arbitrarios que necesitas en el front.

Comment: A lo que me refiero es, a parte de mandar al render del html, mandar también el atributo para accederlo en el javascript del cliente.

Comment: Si vas a renderear una plantilla, la respuesta será HTML. Lo que puedes hacer es que el HTML contenga, por ejemplo, un input de tipo hidden al cual le asignes el valor que quieres usar desde el front. Luego lees el valor desde ese input.